# How do I save user ratings in Django database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

This is my first project in Django. I am trying to save rating in Django database but when I click on radio buttons the value doesn't store in database. I have tried solutions of Stack Overflow previously uploaded but none helped me in resolving my issue. I was firstly using *RadioSelect* in *forms.py* but still having the same problem.

Here is the code:

**Model.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=120,default="None")
    model = models.CharField(max_length=120,default="None")
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=120 , default="Phone")
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=39.99)

class Rating(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,default=None, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,default=None, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

**Views.py**

```
def add_rating(request,id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=id)
    pro = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RatingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            product = form.cleaned_data['product']
            user = form.cleaned_data['user']
            rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']

            product = request.POST.get('product', ''),
            user = request.POST.get('user', ''),
            rating = request.POST.get('rating', ''),

            obj = Rating(product=product, user=user, rating=rating)
            obj.save()
            context = {'obj': obj}
            return render(request, 'product/detail.html',context)
        else:
           form=RatingForm()
        return HttpResponse('Please rate the product')
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Rating

class RatingForm(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
      model = Rating
      fields = ('product', 'user','rating')
```

**template.py**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'add_rating' product.id %}">{%    csrf_token %}
<ul class="rate-area" style="display:inline;position:absolute">
<input type="radio" id="5-star" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="5-   star" title="Amazing">5 stars</label>
<input type="radio" id="4-star" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="4-star" title="Good">4 stars</label>
<input type="radio" id="3-star" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="3-star" title="Average">3 stars</label>
<input type="radio" id="2-star" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="2-star" title="Not Good">2 stars</label>
<input type="radio" id="1-star" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="1-star" title="Bad">1 star</label>
<button type="submit" value="Rate">Rate</button>

</ul>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a "CharField" on your model while you should be using a "ChoiceField",  a ChoiceField would then become a dropdown select.

It would also be easier to use generic editing views; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Comment: Thank you so much @Kevin D. I have modified CharField as ChoiceField but the values are not storing in database.

Comment: How do you generate your form?  Do you use {{ form }} to generate the form or are you manually looping through all fields?, it looks like I'm missing some items here.

Comment: I am not using {{ form }}. I want to do it by looping through the fields

Comment: That explains why, start using {{ form }} to generate a form and perform testing. If that's all ok you can render your form manually, it does require some work, check the following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kevin for your precious time. Issue resolved. I wasn't using **widget forms.RadioSelect**  in forms.py for rating.